# Dismiss Keyboard when editing UItextfield on Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitextfield

i want to make a calculator with two textfield. there are numbers buttons and mathematical operations buttons. but i couldn't dismiss keyboard when clicking textfield. i never want to show keyboard but , want to edit textfield with numbers buttons.

touchbegans or textFieldShoulBeginEditing method didn't worked for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Edit**

This workaround was specific for the above question , so stop downvote this answer. This is not about simply dismissing the keyboard. This is about being able to edit the textfield with custom inputView and make the textfield editable when there is no keyboard visible.

This makes your textfields keyboard disappear and still editable .

**Objective-C**

```
yourTextField.inputView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectZero];
```

**Swift**

```
yourTextField.inputView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)
```

Comment: thank you very much ! its worked for me. 
but on Swift code like this : myTextField.inputView = UIView(frame: CGRectZero)

Comment: glad it worked, I did not pay attention to the swift part of the question. edited my answer!

Answer (score 7):

An answer to your question on how to dismiss the keyboard in Xcode 6.1 using Swift below:

```
import UIKit

class ItemViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var textFieldItemName: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var textFieldQt: UITextField!

    @IBOutlet var textFieldMoreInfo: UITextField!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        textFieldItemName.delegate = self
        textFieldQt.delegate = self
        textFieldMoreInfo.delegate = self
    }

                       ...

    /**
     * Called when 'return' key pressed. return NO to ignore.
     */
    func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
        return true
    }


   /**
    * Called when the user click on the view (outside the UITextField).
    */
   override func touchesBegan(touches: NSSet, withEvent event: UIEvent) {
        self.view.endEditing(true)
   }

}
```

([Source of this information](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0YMNmLK0694)).

Comment: Nice answer. Setting the delegate is definitely needed for multiple textfields.

Comment: Nice answers, a lot of bad ones out there. This makes sense and works well. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
self.endEditing = YES;
```

In your ViewController

Comment: but i can't select uitextfield with endEditing ? can you explain more

Comment: When keyboard dismisses you obviously can not use UITextfield. But When tapping on textfield again it gets activated again

Comment: so, self.endEditing = YES where will i use ? inside "textFieldShouldBeginEditing" method ? thanks for your response

Comment: Where you want to dismiss there you keep this code.

Answer (score 0):

I've got solution from [Ezimet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25403102/11077258)'s answer

For **Swift 5**

```
myTextField.inputView = UIView(frame: CGRect.zero)
```